# WinSCP .NET File resume not working while downloading

Tags: .net, winscp, winscp-net

I were using WinSCP .NET assembly for file downloading. Now I needed to support file resume functionality.

For that what I have done is

```
var options = new TransferOptions();
options.ResumeSupport.State = TransferResumeSupportState.On;
```

And in my code for downloading I have done

```
 TransferOperationResult transferResult = session.GetFiles(
     _appSettings["SFTP_IncomingFileFolder"] + file.Folder + "/" + file.FileName,
     _appSettings["Local_IncomingFileFolder"] + file.Folder + "\\" + file.FileName +".filepart", false, options);
 transferResult.Check();
```

Now to check if file resume work I disconnect while downloading. 
Problem is that every time I now download it starts from zero instead of the place where it left.

Like for 100 MB file if local downloaded length is 30 MB. When I try to reconnect it starts from zero length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `.ResumeSupport` works for SFTP only.
2. It works only if you had that flag set already when downloading the first piece, so that the piece has `.filepart` extension (it should the be case though as the default is to do that for all files over 100 KB).
3. The `.filepart` extension is added automatically. If you add one explicitly, WinSCP will look for `.filepart.filepart`. So do not add the extension yourself.
4. The explicit resume is [supported since WinSCP 5.9](https://winscp.net/tracker/1358).
   Set the [`TransferOptions.OverwriteMode` property](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferoptions#overwritemode) to `OverwriteMode.Resume`.

---

Reference:

- [`TransferResumeSupport` Class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_transferresumesupport)
- [Automatic resuming / Transfer to temporary filename](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume#automatic)

---

If this does not help, please enable logging (`Session.SessionLogPath`) and show us the log.